# How to get server name through code if SQL Server (Standard Edition) is installed

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, connection-string

How to get server name through code if SQL Server (Standard Edition) is installed.

We pass the server name while creating a connection string to connect SQL Server. Can we retrieve this value through code?

```
string sqlConnectionString = string.Format(
"user id={0};password={1};server={2};Trusted_Connection=no;database=TestDB;
connection timeout={3}",
dirDBinfo.UserName, dirDBinfo.Password, "ServerName", dirDBinfo.TimeOut);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want.

If you already have a connection string, and you are trying to extract the server name from it for use elsewhere, you can reverse-engineer it like so:

```
var parser = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
var serverName = parser.DataSource;
```

If you are constructing your connection string for the first time, then:

1. If you know that you want to connect to the SQL Server on the machine that your client code is executing on, then just use `(local)` for the server name. If the SQL Server has an instance name, then specify it like this: `(local)\myinstancename`.
2. If you don't know in advance what server to connect to, then it's up to you to obtain that information from somewhere else.

Comment: I agree - it sounds like Ashish is trying to get the application to guess which server to use, which it simply can't do. Other than picking the default local instance via `(local)` the only other sensible option is to TELL the code which server to use. How you do that is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server on the local computer?
If so, set the server name to `localhost`.
If not, [use SqlDataSourceEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2.aspx).

---

Also, instead of building a connection string using `String.Format`, you should use a [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).  This will handle values with semicolons.

For example:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

builder.UserID = dirDBinfo.UserName;
builder.Password = dirDBinfo.Password;
builder.Server= "localhost";
builder.UserID = dirDBinfo.UserName;
builder["Trusted_Connection"] = "no";
builder.Database = "TestDB"
builder.ConnectTimeout = dirDBinfo.TimeOut;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just execute SELECT @@SERVERNAME against this connection?

Comment: so we are still building our connection string? In this case what is the logic that determines which SQL server to choose? If it is local, then as you said - just use localhost. But I thought we already had server name passed and now we need to retrieve it somehow in the code...

Comment: As I understand the question, that's what he's asking.